# How can I insert at a certain spot in array

Tags: c, arrays, struct

My code appends every new employee I add to the list. I want it to replace the area I just removed. So if I were to remove 333 and I add 666 I want it to be the second in the list instead of it being at the end

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 4

struct Employ {
    int ID;
    int age;
    double salary;
};

int main(void) {
    struct Employ emp[SIZE]={{0}};
    int option = 1;
    int nEmp = 0;
    int i;
    int searchedI;
    int check;
    int sID;
    printf("---=== EMPLOYEE DATA ===---\n\n");
    while (option != 0) {
        printf("1. Display Employee Information\n");
        printf("2. Add Employee\n");
        printf("3. Update Employee Salary\n");
        printf("4. Remove Employee\n");
        printf("0. Exit\n\n");
        printf("Please select from the above options: ");
        scanf("%d", &option);
        printf("\n");
        switch (option)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("EMP ID  EMP AGE EMP SALARY\n");
                printf("======  ======= ==========\n");
                for (i = 0; i < nEmp; i++) {
                    printf("%6d%9d%11.2lf\n", emp[i].ID, emp[i].age, emp[i].salary);
                }
                printf("\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Adding Employee\n");
                printf("===============\n");
                if (nEmp == SIZE) {
                    printf("ERROR!!! Maximum Number of Employees Reached\n\n");
                }
                else {
                    check = 1;
                    while (check) {
                        printf("Enter Employee ID: ");
                        scanf("%d", &emp[nEmp].ID);
                        printf("Enter Employee Age: ");
                        scanf("%d", &emp[nEmp].age);
                        printf("Enter Employee Salary: ");
                        scanf("%lf", &emp[nEmp].salary);
                        if (emp[nEmp].ID < 0 || emp[nEmp].age < 0 || emp[nEmp].salary < 0) printf("\nAll number should be positive\n");
                        else check = 0;
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                    nEmp++;
                }
                break;
            case 3:       //update employee
                printf("Update Employee Salary\n");
                printf("======================\n");
                if (nEmp == 0) {
                    printf("\nNo employee to update\n\n");
                    break;
                }
                do
                {
                    check = 1;
                    printf("Enter Employee ID: ");
                    scanf("%d", &sID);
                    for (i = 0; i < nEmp; i++)
                    {
                        if (emp[i].ID == sID) break;
                        else if (i == nEmp - 1) printf("*** ERROR: Employee ID not found! ***\n");
                    }
                    if (i != nEmp) {
                        printf("The current salary is %.2f\n", emp[i].salary);
                        printf("Enter Employee New Salary: ");
                        scanf("%lf", &emp[i].salary);
                        check = 0;
                        printf("\n");
                    }
                } while (check);
                break;
            case 4:          //remove employee
                printf("Remove Employee\n");
                printf("===============\n");
                if (nEmp == 0) {
                    printf("\nNo employee to remove\n\n");
                    break;
                }
                do
                {
                    check = 1;
                    printf("Enter Employee ID: ");
                    scanf("%d", &sID);
                    for (i = 0; i < nEmp; i++)
                    {
                        if (emp[i].ID == sID) break;
                        else if (i == nEmp - 1) printf("*** ERROR: Employee ID not found! ***\n");
                    }
                    if (i != nEmp) {
                        check = 0;
                        searchedI = i;

                        printf("Employee %d will be removed\n\n", emp[searchedI].ID);

                        for (i = searchedI; i < nEmp; i++)
                        {
                            if (i != nEmp - 1) emp[i] = emp[i + 1];
                            else emp[i].ID = 0;


                        }
                        nEmp -= 1;

                    }

                } while (check);

                break;
            case 0:
                printf("Exiting Employee Data Program. Good Bye!!!\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("ERROR: Incorrect Option: Try Again\n\n");
                break;
        }

    }
    return 1;
}
```

original list 
222
333 
444

I expect the list to show 
222
666
444

results showing right now is 
222
444
666

Comment: Mark the deleted array element as unused, for example by setting its `ID` member to `-1`, so it is ignored by a search or by printing, but can be recycled.

Comment: so emp[i].ID=-1 ? after the nEmp-=1

Comment: Sorry can you explain in more dept I dont understand

Comment: Instead of closing the gap left by the deletion, mark it as unused. Then the new record can use the same array element.

Comment: An array is not a list.  To insert into an array, you need to move all the later entries by one.  This can be an expensive procedure and is one of the primary motivations for using a list instead.  With a linked list, insertion is an O(1) operation.  Know your data structures, and choose the right one.

Comment: you remain silent => I deleted my answer

Answer (score 0):

When deleting a value, you could replace it with a placeholder (like infinity for example) instead of removing it out of the list. When you later on want to add a new value to the list, you can scan the list for this placeholder and:

- if it exists: replace it with the new value
- if the list does not contain this placeholder: add the value to the end of the list